# SVG mouseover show hide on hotspots

Tags: html, svg, hide, show

I've created a map image with overlaying hotspots. It was created in inkscape and exported as an SVG.
The map is a test sketch only. http://wilsonvisuals.art/zenmapillo/imagemap_responsive2.html
I have pasted the SVG code into an html page with css.
I am now trying to add mouse over functionality to the hotspots.
When the user mouses over a hotspot it shows a tooltip or other card. And hides again when moused off.

I've tried several methods of inserting html/css code into the svg code but never works. The one below is simple html css.

- I's this method workable? and how would I fix it?
- Is Javascript a better approach to this? I got it working this way but the sample code I used performed a different function than what I want. Is there some sample code specific to show/hide on mouseover? (I am Javascript illiterate).
  Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>Zen Maps - Courtney & Comox, Vancouver Island</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    
    <style>
    #myBtn {
    margin: auto;
      z-index: 99;
      font-size: 18px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      background-color: #4a178bff;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 15px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    #myBtn:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }
    
    div {
      text-align: center;
    }
    h2 {
      color: #4287f5;
    }
    .hide {
      display: none;
      border: 5px double #b4b8bf;
    }
    
    .hide2 {
      display: none;
      border: 5px double #b4b8bf;
    }
    
    .hide3 {
      display: none;
      border: 5px double #b4b8bf;
    }
    a {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover + span {
      display: block;
      color: #4287f5;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    a.two {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a.two:hover + span {
      display: block;
      color: #4287f5;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    a.three {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a.three:hover + span {
      display: block;
      color: #4287f5;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    </style>
    <body>
    <div class="mapdiv">
    
    <!----to make svg responsive change fixed width to percentage and remove height property in the svg tag---->
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
     <!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
     <svg
        version="1.1"
        id="svg366"
        width="3272.7273"
        height="2029.0909"
        viewBox="0 0 3272.7273 2029.0909"
        sodipodi:docname="Comox3hotspot.svg"
        inkscape:version="1.2 (dc2aeda, 2022-05-15)"
        inkscape:export-filename="Comox1hotspot.png"
        inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
        inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
        xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
        xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <defs
          id="defs370" />
       <sodipodi:namedview
          id="namedview368"
          pagecolor="#ffffff"
          bordercolor="#000000"
          borderopacity="0.25"
          inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
          inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
          inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
          inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
          showgrid="false"
          inkscape:zoom="0.38072222"
          inkscape:cx="1086.0937"
          inkscape:cy="1016.4891"
          inkscape:window-width="1732"
          inkscape:window-height="1290"
          inkscape:window-x="0"
          inkscape:window-y="25"
          inkscape:window-maximized="0"
          inkscape:current-layer="g372" />
       <g
          inkscape:groupmode="layer"
          inkscape:label="Image"
          id="g372">
         <image
            width="3272.7273"
            height="2029.0909"
            preserveAspectRatio="none"
            xlink:href="maps/Comox12.jpg"
            id="image374" />
            
            
            <a xlink:href="http://travelalberta.com/">
            <clipPath id="alberta-clipper">
            <path id="CA-AB" d="M1932…"/>
            </clipPath>
            <image clip-path="url(#alberta-clipper)"
            width="1024" height="768"
            xlink:href="crowsnest-pass.jpg" x="1300" y="150">
            </image>
            </a>
            
         <a xlink:href="http://travelalberta.com/">   
         <path
            style="opacity:1;fill:#310000"
            d="m 853.64075,499.05151 c -152.34204,-2.62658 -152.34204,-2.62658 -152.34204,-2.62658 l 2.62658,168.10156 212.75354,31.51904 76.17102,-110.31665 z"
            id="path562" />
         </a>
         <foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160">
            <span class="hide"> 
            First Card
            </span>
            </foreignObject>
            
          <a xlink:href="http://travelalberta.com/">  
         <path
            style="opacity:1;fill:#333"
            d="m 1452.5026,590.98206 -154.9687,186.48767 383.4817,84.05078 291.5512,7.87976 -112.9433,-309.93726 z"
            id="path6362" />
          </a>
          <foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160">
            <span class="hide2"> 
              Second Card
             </span>
             </foreignObject>
            
            <a xlink:href="http://travelalberta.com/">
         <path
            style="opacity:1;fill:#777"
            d="m 1329.053,1625.8573 57.7849,344.0829 643.5138,36.7722 -139.2091,-378.2285 z"
            id="path6364"
            inkscape:export-filename="path6364.svg"
            inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
            inkscape:export-ydpi="96" />
            </a>
            <foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160">
              <span class="hide3"> 
              Third Card
              </span>
            </foreignObject>
       </g>
     </svg>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `a:hover + span` does not match anything. it's either `a:hover + foreignObject` or `a:hover + foreignObject > span`. There are no `a.two` or `a.three` elements in your code. Note that `margin-top` has no effect on elements in the SVG namespace (the `<a>` element in this case). An [XML prolog](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml#sec-prolog-dtd) in the middle of content is also in error, but will be simply ignored by browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the card outside the svg element. The card can be a div with position absolute (so that you can position it where you need it to be) and   display none that you make visible only when passing over the path.

For clarity i've simplified the code.

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll("path");
paths.forEach((p) => {
    p.addEventListener("mouseleave", (evt) => {
      card.style.display = "none";  
  });
  p.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
    let pos = oMousePos(svg, evt);
    let text = p.dataset.text;
   
    card.style.display = "block";
    card.style.top = pos.y + "px";
    card.style.left = pos.x + "px";
    card.innerHTML = text;
  });

});

function oMousePos(element, evt) {
  let ClientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  };
}
```

```css
#card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  border: solid;
  background: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  color:red;
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 3272.7273 2029.0909" id="svg" >


  <g id="g372">
    <image width="3272.7273" height="2029.0909" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="maps/Comox12.jpg" id="image374" />

    <a xlink:href="http://travelalberta.com/">
      <path style="opacity:1;fill:#310000" d="m 853.64075,499.05151 c -152.34204,-2.62658 -152.34204,-2.62658 -152.34204,-2.62658 l 2.62658,168.10156 212.75354,31.51904 76.17102,-110.31665 z" id="path562" data-text="first Card" />
    </a>
  

    <a xlink:href="http://travelalberta.com/">
      <path style="opacity:1;fill:#333" d="m 1452.5026,590.98206 -154.9687,186.48767 383.4817,84.05078 291.5512,7.87976 -112.9433,-309.93726 z" id="path6362" data-text="Second Card" />
    </a>
   

    <a xlink:href="http://travelalberta.com/">
      <path style="opacity:1;fill:#777" d="m 1329.053,1625.8573 57.7849,344.0829 643.5138,36.7722 -139.2091,-378.2285 z" id="path6364" data-text="third Card" />
    </a>

  </g>
</svg>

<div id="card"></div>
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks so much. Just one final thing if its even possible.
I would like to be able to format the information on the card with css. Is it possible to show a div by id instead of basic text???

Comment: but you can format it with css. I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by _show a div by id instead of basic text_. Please ask a different question and giva all the details.

Comment: "but you can format it with css" What i meant to say is

Comment: "but you can format it with css" Thanks, thats exactly what I want to do, format with html and css. I tried adding a simple H4 class inside the data text but didnt work, same when I added outside. Could you give me a quick simple sample? I'm pretty sure I can take it from there and expand. Thanks!

Comment: You don't add the class to the data. The data is for the text content. You need to apply css to the #card. In the example above I've added a color for the text and a padding

Comment: Sorry i meant format the text into several different sizes and styles. I tried a few other things and I've been able to add html font tags around the text. When I try to add a css class to the htnl font tag it breaks. Not sure if this is the correct way to do things but sems to work. This how i set it up               data-text="<h4><tspan>Bobs Boquets</tspan></h4><h5>23rd street NW Flower Ave</h5><h6>Next to Widget World</h6>"       It can be viewed here         http://wilsonvisuals.art/zenmapillo/imagemap_responsive3.html

Comment: In this case you may need several data attributes like `data-h4`, `data-h5`, `data-h6`. Yet another way would be using a json or an objects array and take the data from there

Comment: Sounds good thanks so much for your help! I'm finally getting this functioning the way I wanted.